# Problemas ao otimizar sistema de login com autoload

Tags: php, php-autoload, spl-autoloader-register

Fiz uma otimização no sistema de *login* e como tive problemas com diretório resolvi pesquisar na web e encontrei um recurso legal do PHP que é o *autoload*. Fiz toda a implementação de acordo com os exemplos que obtive mas estou tendo problemas.

Segue como meu código está:

Tudo começa pela `index.php`, que está na raiz do projeto.

**index.php**

```
<?php
 // Adicionando o arquivo de autoload, que faz o carregamento dos diretórios de forma dinâmica.
 require_once( "autoload.php" );

 // Verificando se existe a sessão.
 session_start(); 

 // A sessão ainda não existe. Primeiro acesso do usuário.
 if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'logado' ] ) ) {
 header( 'location:login.php' );
 }

 // A sessão do usuário já existe. Vericando se ainda está logado.
 elseif ( $_SESSION[ 'logado' ] == false)  { 
 header( 'location:login.php' );
 } 

 // Usuário já conectado. Envia direto para a página inicial.
 else {
 header( 'location:inicio.php' );
 }
?>
```

A primeira tarefa do PHP é acrescentar o `autoload.php`, que também está na raiz do projeto. Segue ele abaixo:

**autoload.php**

```
<?php

 // Função que carrega as classes da pasta "database".
 function carregar_classes_database( $class ) {

    if ( file_exists( "database/" . strtolower( $class ) . ".class.php" ) ) {
        require_once( "database/" . strtolower( $class ) . ".class.php" );
    }
 }

 spl_autoload_register( "carregar_classes_database" );

 $obj1 = new Database();

 // Função que carrega as classes da pasta "entity".
 function carregar_classes_usuario( $class ) {
    if ( file_exists( "entity/usuario/" . strtolower( $class ) . ".class.php" ) ) {
        require_once( "entity/usuario/" . strtolower( $class ) . ".class.php" );
    }
 }

 spl_autoload_register( "carregar_classes_usuario" );

 $obj2 = new Usuario();

?>
```

Já coloquei um `echo` dentro do `if` do `file_exists` só para assegurar que o arquivo realmente está válido e está.

Minha estrutura de diretórios está no seguinte formato:

[image: diretórios]

Como minha sessão não existe no primeiro acesso ao site, eu sou encaminhado para o *login*. Neste momento o `autoload.php` já foi adicionado.

Chego na tela de login, onde tenho o *input* de usuário e o *input* de senha e também o botão *submit*.

A `action` do `form` chama uma função de validação de login, que eu chamei de `validarLogin.php`

**validarLogin.php**

```
<?php 
  // Adicionando recursos. COMENTADO PARA UTILIZAR O AUTOLOAD E EVITAR INCLUIR OS ARQUIVOS "NA MÃO".
  //require_once( "database/database.class.php" );
  //require_once( "entity/usuario/usuario.class.php" );
​
  session_start(); 
  $database = new Database();
  $database->connect();

  // Conexão bem sucedida.
  if ( $database->getConnected() ) {

    $user = new Usuario();
    $user->setUsuario( $_POST[ 'usuario' ] );
    $user->setSenha( $_POST[ 'senha' ] );

    // Validando se o usuário e a senha são válidos.
    if ( $user->exists( true, '' ) ) {

      $_SESSION[ 'erro' ]    = ''; 
      $_SESSION[ 'logado' ]  = true; 
      $_SESSION[ 'usuario' ] = $user->getUsuario(); 
      $_SESSION[ 'nome' ]    = $user->getNome() . ' ' . $user->getSobrenome(); 

      header('location:inicio.php');
    // Se o usuário for inválido volta para a tela de login.
    } else {

      $_SESSION[ 'erro' ]    = $user->getMSG_INVALID_USER(); 
      $_SESSION[ 'logado' ]  = false; 
      $_SESSION[ 'usuario' ] = ''; 
      $_SESSION[ 'nome' ]    = ''; 

      header('location:login.php');

    }

  } 

  // Ocorreu um erro na conexão. Volta para a página de login.
  else {

    $_SESSION[ 'erro' ]    = $database->getMsgError(); 
    $_SESSION[ 'logado' ]  = false; 
    $_SESSION[ 'usuario' ] = ''; 
    $_SESSION[ 'nome' ]    = ''; 
    header('location:login.php');

  }

 ?>
```

Comentei os `require_once`, pois, na minha cabeça, se eu já estou usando o `autoload`, eu não preciso mais dos `required_once`.

Quando eu submeto o formulário de *login* e a função acima é chamada eu tenho um erro na linha:

```
  $database = new Database();
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Database' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/validarLogin.php on line 10 Call Stack: 0.4673 238080 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/validarLogin.php:0​

Por quê eu estou tendo esse erro se o meu *autoload* já foi iniciado?

O PHP não deveria tomar conhecimento de quem é a classe `Database`, uma vez que ela já está em memória?

Comment: Mas a função de *autoload* só existirá se você carregar o arquivo `autoload.php`. No caso, em `validarLogin.php` você precisará fazer o `require_once("autoload.php")` também.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Anderson. Realmente, quando coloquei a chamada ao autoload.php no validarLogin.php funcionou. Mas esse ainda é um problema pra mim pois eu preciso chamar o autoload em todos os arquivos .php, o que não seria muito diferente de chamar o require_once. Decidi estudar Laravel para utiliza-lo no desenvolvimento e evitar esses tipos de problemas. Mesmo assim, agradeço sua disposição em ajudar.